# Angular ngFor only sets value of last output

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a for loop that runs with a component inside it. The component emits a value that the element in the loop needs to set an if. Problem is all elements in the loops use the last emit's value. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="counter === 0">
      <app-my-comp (itemSize)="setCounter($event)"></app-my-comp>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

where `setCounter` takes the itemSize and sets the `counter` value. Instead of using the `counter` value set in each item in the loop only the last value is being used. I need to only use the value for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Pass data from parent to child with input binding https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: A small example would be helpful, but what I believe you are doing is setting `counter` variable of the parent after a child emits. Every child will modify the same parent variable.

Comment: How you're going to try different counter values having only one reference? You want to try counter === 0 or counter === i (*ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;")

Comment: What is a counter? It will be helpful to share the component.ts code having this template.